# create_logout_url acting wierdly

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use `create_logout_url` to create a sort of admin menu in a trivial appengine-site, but it is currently behaving quite wierdly. Take a look at the code below:

```
menu = []

logout_link = "<a href='%s'>Log out</a>" % users.create_logout_url('/blog')
menu.append(logout_link)

new_entry = ''
if users.is_current_user_admin():
new_entry = "<a href='%(newpost)s'>New entry</a>" % {'newpost': self.uri_for('blog_entry')}
menu.append(new_entry)
return ','.join(menu)
```

The expected output should be something like:

```
<a href='/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/blog&action=Logout'>Log out</a>,<a href='/blog/newpost'>New entry</a>
```

But it's actually:

```
<a href="<a href='/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/blog&action=Logout'>Log out</a>,<a href='/blog/newpost'>New entry</a>">Log out</a>
```

Any ideas?

### Update

I'm trying to use the above code in my base handler (which contains a lot of code that gets reused everywhere, like this admin menu and templating functions), if it helps or matters.

Changing the `logout_link`-part to:

```
logout_link = users.create_logout_url('/blog')
```

Results in the following output:

```
<a href="/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/blog&action=Logout,<a href='/blog/newpost'>New entry</a>">Log out</a>
```

(I'd already tried that before, however, but to no avail)

Comment: Tangentially, why are you building your pages like this? You're creating a lot of trouble for yourself, that templating systems were designed to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Monotux, could you provide us with some more details about your code. You said you are using some other menus and templating functions.

The snippet provided generates the correct code:

```
<a href='/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/blog&action=Logout'>Log out</a>,<a href='/blog/newpost'>New entry</a>
```

And given the two outputs you are seeing:

```
<a href="<a href='/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/blog&action=Logout'>Log out</a>,<a href='/blog/newpost'>New entry</a>">Log out</a>
<a href="/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/blog&action=Logout,<a href='/blog/newpost'>New entry</a>">Log out</a>
```

wich both are of the form

```
<a href='...'>Log out</a>
```

I think you are embedding the response of the snippet in some other code.